# C# Oracle command Parameters add. How can I add part of the text itself into the command text?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

For example below is my code:

ss.StoreNumber is string from user, store_no is int type in database.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM SALES_STATUS WHERE store_no = :SerchStore";
//Creating cmd using sql and conn
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
//Create Parameters to add value
if (int.TryParse(ss.StoreNumber, out int n) == true)
{
cmd.Parameters.Add("SerchStore", int.Parse(ss.StoreNumber));
}
else
{
cmd.Parameters.Add("SerchStore", "store_no");
}
```

Simple function, I want to create a SQL application, if user type in store number, then it will return the sales status by the store number.

Otherwise, if user didn't type in anything or typed in any non-numeric information in the store number text box, then it should return information from all stores.

I used below code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("SerchStore", "store_no");
```

because I want to make it into this Query, which is working in Oracle Develoepr:

```
SELECT * FROM SALES_STATUS WHERE store_no = store_no;
```

So my question is, what should I put into below "X" to make the query to be the query I want above?

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("SerchStore", X);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this I'd just run a different query:

```
string sql = "";
if (int.TryParse(ss.StoreNumber, out int n) == true)
{
  sql = "SELECT * FROM SALES_STATUS WHERE store_no = :SerchStore";
}
else
{
  sql = "SELECT * FROM SALES_STATUS;"
}    
//Creating cmd using sql and conn
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);

//Create Parameters to add value
if (int.TryParse(ss.StoreNumber, out int n) == true)
{
  cmd.Parameters.Add("SerchStore", int.Parse(ss.StoreNumber));
}
```

If it was in a stored procedure, you might do something like "OR :SerchStore is NULL", but since you're sending the query from C# code, just send the query you want to send.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am trying not to create 2 queries. Because this is a dummy query, My real query is very long including 3 parameters they can all be null. So I need to create 6 queries...Is that anyway that I can make it done in one query?

Comment: so you put "OR <theparameter> is null" into your query.

`select *
 from your_table
 where (your_column = :your_parameter
            or :your_parameter is null)`

Comment: Or build your query dynamically - instead of writing multiple fully separate query strings, you build the string in steps so you can apply logic to the text. Still use parameters - you can use dynamic SQL safely.

Answer (score 0):

Parameterized queries are meant to prevent the thing you are trying to do right now (sql injection).

how you could do this is first check the user input and get the appropriate query depending on if the input is valid or not.